# In Whenever gem, if we use every :month, does it mean the end of month or beginning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

When using the `whenever` gem we can set a monthly job like this :

```
every :month do
    ...
end
```

Will this run the job at the end of the month or at the start of the month? I want to run it at the end.

Comment: just check the crontab? also/or try reading the docs/source

Comment: That will probably be the easiest. The hardest part of that might be interpreting the arcane crontab syntax, but [there are tools](http://www.cronchecker.net/) for that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the tests in whenever repo](https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/e69022e6aab551aed4f60608e7ee6c3cbab87dde/test/unit/cron_test.rb#L194):

```
assert_equal '0 0 1 * *',  parse_time(:month)
```

So `:month` will generate a cron entry that looks like `0 0 1 * *..`

This corresponds to [run once a month at midnight of the first day of the month](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Nonstandard_predefined_scheduling_definitions).

One way to make the job run last day of the month would be to use the raw cron entry in wherever as follows:

```
every '0 0 L * *' do
  ...
end
```

This assumes that the cron on the server supports the `L` flag for representing the last day of the month.

See [Cron job to run on the last day of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139189/cron-job-to-run-on-the-last-day-of-the-month) for more about running a cron job on the last day of the month.