# Schedule a task to work on 15th and the last day of the month in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, scheduled-tasks, whenever

I have defined a rake task to work on the 15th and last day of the month at 8 am in schedule.rb file. I just wanted to confirm if I have done it the right way. Please have a look and suggest it.

## run this task at 8am on 15th of every month

```
every '0 8 15 * *' do
  rake 'office:reminder', environment: ENV['RAILS_ENV']
end
```

## run this task at 8am on the last day of every month

```
every '0 8 28-31 * *' do
  rake 'office:reminder', environment: ENV['RAILS_ENV']
end
```

Comment: `0 8 28-31 * *` will run the job at 8am on 28th, 29th, 30th and 31st.

Comment: @Stefan how can I make it run for the last day of the month?

Comment: AFAIK you can't specify "last day of month" in cron. A possible workaround is to specify `0 8 * * *`, i.e. run the task every day at 8am and move the day handling into the rake task. To avoid hard-coding the values, you could pass them as arguments when invoking the task, i.e. `15` and `-1`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30288148/12201472

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6139310/12201472

Comment: I hope, links above will help a little

Comment: I'm not up on cron and rake tasks, but it's ruby running the above code, right? So you could put `require 'active_support'` at the top and leverage those methods?

Comment: There's tools like [Fugit](https://github.com/floraison/fugit) that can turn English descriptions of intervals into `cron` notation. See: `Fugit::Nat.parse`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `cron` has a very simple interface it's hard to convey a concept like "last day of month" to it without outside help. But you could shift your logic into the task:

```
every '0 8 28-31 * *' do
  rake 'office:end_of_month_reminder', environment: ENV['RAILS_ENV']
end
```

And in a new task called office:end_of_month_reminder:

```
if Date.today.day == Date.today.end_of_month.day
  #your task here
else
  puts "not the end of the month, skipping"
end
```

You would still have your first-of-the-month task. But if you wanted to roll it into one:

```
every '0 8 15,28-31 * *' do
  rake 'office:reminder', environment: ENV['RAILS_ENV']
end
```

And in your task:

```
if (Date.today.day == 15) || (Date.today.day == Date.today.end_of_month.day) 
  #your task here
else
  puts "not the first or last of the month, skipping"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

cron usually doesn't allow to specify "last day of the month". But in Ruby, you can simply use `-1` to denote the month's last day:

```
Date.new(2020, 2, -1)
#=> Sat, 29 Feb 2020
```

So instead of having separate entries for specific days, you could define one entry running every day at 8am and pass the days as [arguments](https://ruby.github.io/rake/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html#label-Tasks+with+Arguments) to the rake task:

```
every '0 8 * * *' do
  rake 'office:reminder[15,-1]', environment: ENV['RAILS_ENV']
end
```

Then weithin your task, you can turn these arguments into date objects and check if any of them is equal to today's date:

```
namespace :office do
  task :reminder do |t, args|
    days = args.extras.map(&:to_i)
    today = Date.today
    if days.any? { |day| today == Date.new(today.year, today.month, day) }
      # send your reminder
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: From what I'm reading `cron` has `0 0 0 L * ? *` which means "last day of the month"

Comment: @Beartech `L` is a non-standard extension.