# How to write or update into properties file present in application context scope and read updated data from same properties file

Tags: java, spring, cron

I'm using Spring 3.0 and JSF 2.0. I've a requirement that some piece of code has to run on last day of every month. For that I'm using Spring support cron job feature. I'm able to run 1st day of every month, but how do I get the last day of every month? Because depending on the month, the last day (i.e date) will vary.

Comment: What does this have to do with properties?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139189/cron-job-to-run-on-the-last-day-of-the-month

Comment: Just use one of any of the Date APIs that are available in Java

Comment: Hi BalusC 1st day of every month i'll calculate the last date of that month and i'll store that date into properties file. This means every month i'll get new date to run the job. And i refer the link you given i didnt understand where to "*.sh" file.