# How to run a job at end of month by using whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to run a rake task at end of month, but according to the post below cron doesn't provide a easy way for it.

[Cron job to run on the last day of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139189/cron-job-to-run-on-the-last-day-of-the-month)

Therefore I wrote like this:

```
every "50 23 30 4,6,9,11 *" do
  rbenv_rake "foo:update"
end
every "50 23 31 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 *" do
  rbenv_rake "foo:update"
end
every "50 23 28 2 *" do
  rbenv_rake "foo:update"
end
```

Is there wrapper method in whenever to write the code simpler?

Comment: 0 50 23 L * ? did you give this a try. i checked this link from http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger. not sure if it is going to help you. because wiki says L is non standard. but you can give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, but if it's non standard way I'll stick the way I wrote. Even if it works in my current environment, I don't want to use uncertain code.

Comment: yes that would be best approach. keep things standardize

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you run some script 10 minutes later?

```
every "0 0 1 * *" do
  rbenv_rake "foo:update"
end
```

Comment: Because in the script I'm using date, so it works differently.

Answer (score 0):

Should try this -

```
  every 1.month, :at => '00:00am' do
    rbenv_rake "foo:update"
  end
```