# Pass today's date as argument for a cron job

Tags: date, cron, report

I have a cronjob that will be launched at the end of each month to generate a monthly report.

Here I found how to launch the job at the end of each month:
 [Cron job to run on the last day of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139189/cron-job-to-run-on-the-last-day-of-the-month)

Now, I just want the date of the last day of the month as an argument for the script.

For example:

```
compute_monthly_rate -e **2016.01.31**
```

How can I pass this date as an argument?

Answer (score 9):

Most implementations of `cron` pass a command string to `/bin/sh` so depending on what it is on your system and what implementation of `date` you have you may have luck with this:

```
compute_monthly_rate -e $(date +%Y.%m.%d)
```

Try it in a terminal first:

```
$ date +%Y.%m.%d
2016.02.02
```

Answer (score 2):

Just extending above answer,

In most of the cases, the Cron jobs takes relative dates like re-index last 15 days stats / logs, etc.

the date command can be used as,

`date -d '-15days' +'%Y-%m-%d'`

`-d, --date` option specifies the date

`+'%Y-%m-%d'` is the date format.

The date command accepts multiple format specifier check the `date --help` for full command reference.