# Adjust cron for 30th of month

Tags: bash, cron

I have the following, simple entry in `crontab -e` pertaining to an event that happens twice every month:

`12 9 15,30 * * /home/run_ps.sh`

For months with <30 days, I need to check on the first of the following month. Is there an elegant way to do this within crontab? I.e., more elegant than changing to `12 9 1,15,30 * * /home/run_ps.sh` and checking the day of month within the script

Comment: check out the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139189/cron-job-to-run-on-the-last-day-of-the-month)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is only one month with less than 30 days and the following month is March.

Add the following additional job, which only runs on March 1st.

```
12 9 1 3 * /home/run_ps.sh
```