# AWS auto snapshot Schedule for last day of the month

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

Hi If I open CloudWatch I have the option of Creating Schedule Snapshot. My challenge is scheduling a Snapshot once every last day of the month.

[image: Event Source]

Comment: In this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139189/cron-job-to-run-on-the-last-day-of-the-month) there are many possibilities explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Scheduler supports "L" to be used as the last day of the month. You can find it documented here - 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html

> The L wildcard in the Day-of-month or Day-of-week fields specifies the
>   last day of the month or week.