# How to schedule a Cron job for multiple days every month?

Tags: cron, airflow-scheduler

I wish to schedule a airflow job for specific set of dates every month, for example 11th and last day of every month and used the below scheduler expression

```
25 14 11,L * * # At 2:45 pm on 11th and last day of every month
```

When I validated the above in https://crontab.guru/ and http://cron.schlitt.info/ i was told the expression as invalid.

Is it possible to schedule together for a known and a unknown (here last) day of every month?  If not is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe your cron does not support the "L" flag. you can refer to this [CRON job to run on the last day of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139189/cron-job-to-run-on-the-last-day-of-the-month)