# How to schedule an AWS lambda cron to run 7 days before the end of the month?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron, serverless-framework

I'm trying to schedule an AWS lambda to run 7 days before the end of the month, using the Serverless framework, but I just can't figure it out. Is there a way to specify a *minus something* with the `L` wildcard? Looks like `L-7` doesn't work.
Thanks.

Comment: Might be useful: [automation - CRON job to run on the last day of the month - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139189/cron-job-to-run-on-the-last-day-of-the-month)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
59 23 L-7 * ? *
```

[image]