# CronJob schedule for every month at the 30 day

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron, aws-event-bridge

I have a aws event beige rule CronJob schedule for every month at the 30 day, my question is it will run on February ?

or what cron expression will accomplish that the cron job run on the last day of every month.

thanks.

Comment: Why do you run on the 30th? Is the actual need to run on the last day of the month, and the 30th is just being used as a convenient alternative? You might be interested in: [CRON job to run on the last day of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6139189/174777)